# Boiling of my motorvehicle

Tags: maintenance

I have a Madza Scrum/ Suzuki curry small truck which is boiling whenever i travell just 5 kilometers, please help what might be the problem

Comment: Have you checked the fluid level? Is there anything obstructing the flow of air through the radiator?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with both a car and a motorcycle in the past. In both cases the problem was a seized thermostat.

Here is some more info on testing your thermostat: [How can I test my thermostat?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/23767/how-can-i-test-my-thermostat)

If the thermostat is the problem, I'd recommend replacing it, but gutting it is also an option,

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove and test the thermostat to ensure it's opening at the right temp. A bad radiator/cap/blockage could also be causing a problem. That could include air in the system if it needs to be bled out in a special manor.

At worst, it could be a head/gasket problem which you can get a test for from most local autopart stores.